# Python unittest: 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest, nose

I am new to `unittest`. I am trying to skip test cases based on values in a list.

```
class UESpecTest(unittest.TestCase):
    global testcases_exec_list
    testcases = []
    testcases = testcases_exec_list
    @unittest.skipIf('0' not in self.testcases, "Testcase input not given")
    def test_retrieve_spec_info(self):
        read_spec_info.open_csv(self.spec_info)
        assert (bool(self.spec_info) == True) #Raise assertion if dictionary is empty
```

I am getting the below error

```
  File "test_ue_cap_main.py", line 39, in UESpecTest
    @unittest.skipIf('0' not in self.testcases, "Testcase input not given") 
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I am not sure why self is undefined here.

Comment: A question for you: why *would* `self` be defined there?

Comment: Why did you think it would be defined? The decorator is *outside* the method, it runs at class definition time before an instance could ever have been created.

Comment: Ah!. Makes sense. Thanks guys

Comment: @Gaara Thanks for letting people know you problem was solved. But the usually way you should indicate that your problem was solved to your satisfaction, it to select the check mark to a user's answer. This marks the answer as "accepted". More info on this can be found in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). I recommend selecting [Alex Hall's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937048/python-unittest-self-is-not-defined/44937134#44937134) answer since he answered first and went more in-depth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self` is not a magic variable like `this` in Java and Javascript. That is why you have to define it as the first parameter in methods. If `self` isn't defined as a parameter or some other kind of variable, it's just not defined, like any other variable. Its name is purely conventional.

(Although if `self` was equivalent to `this` it still wouldn't make sense because there's no instance in question, just the class)

When you're at the class level, you can use other variables at the class level normally. For example:

```
class A:
    x = 1
    y = 2
    z = x + y  # 3
```

So you can remove the `self` and just say `'0' not in testcases`.

Also, you have some weird stuff going on:

```
global testcases_exec_list
testcases = []
testcases = testcases_exec_list
```

1. The line `testcases = []` is completely redundant because you immediately override it.
2. The line `global testcases_exec_list` is probably useless (depending on the rest of the class definition) because `global` is for assignment, not access.
3. Why are you defining `testcases` if you already have `testcases_exec_list`? Do you understand that this makes them the same list, rather than making a copy?

Answer (score 2):

`self` is not defined because `self` doesn't exist. At class definition time, `self` has not been created yet. The only time Python creates `self`, is when you are calling a bound method on an instance of your class. `self` is still a normal variable Python implicitly passes to bound methods.

So in your case, you don't need `self`, just use `testcase` as is:

```
@unittest.skipIf('0' not in testcases, "Testcase input not given")
```

When inside of a class's namespace, variables defined there can be used normally as if they were global:

```
>>> class Class:
    attr1 = 0
    print(attr1)


0
>>>
```